# All web API calls return http 200 but with an undefined result object in a react application

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, axios

I have an ASP.NET + React application which works fine in the local and which was working fine in an Azure server where it was hosted previously. Now, I am trying to publish the application in VPS with Windows Server. The page is loaded fine and the react components works.

However, any action that involves a web api call returns an **undefined** *result* object although it is executed successfully and returns HTTP 200. To make the api calls, I use `axios` from the clientside.

Below I share an example api call. For some reason, when I debug it using Firefox, all variables seem to be `undefined`.  However, as you may see in the second image below, `Request Payload` is set correctly with the intended values.

[image]
[image]

Here is the response tab:

[image]

Below is another piece of code showing the axis code to make an api call. Although the call was made successfully, the result object returned is `undefined`.

[image]

I doubt that some configuration in the server and IIS is causing this. Otherwise, I would not work in the previous server or on the localhost. I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is in the response tab?

Comment: In the first screenshot you're checking request, can you check what's in the response instead?

Comment: @Techuila and @Nadia Chibrikova it only says `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`

Comment: Are you expecting a json response from that post request or a text/html? Based from what you said, I think it's passing a text/html as the content-type of the response header.

Comment: Check the raw response data, it may lead you to something

Comment: @Techuila how can I check that, the raw response data?

Comment: Sorry I don't use firefox, I just assume it has a raw response data. Or you can just go to the headers tab and look for the `content-type`, from there, you'll be able to know what type of content it's passing.

Comment: Response Payload in Firefox (collapse Preview it'll be right under it)

Comment: I think you have to show your API code at least.

Answer (score 0):

The response of the post request is passing a different `content-type` which you're not expecting.

If you're saying that code works on the previous server, then try telling axios that you're expecting an `application/json` instead a `text/html`:

```js
axios({
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  url: '' // your api,
  data: {}
})
```